# Angular canActivate changes URL

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have implemented the `CanActivate` router guard for my Angular 5.2 app. If it returns true the URL does not change, but when it returns false, the URL changes and appends the path to the URL. Everywhere in the app that we change the route it `skipsLocationChange` so the URL never changes, but it does in this case. This is what the `canActivate` code looks like basically.

```
canActivate(){
  if(someRightsThatReturnsTrue)
    return true;
  else{
    this.router.navigateByURL('noauthpage', {skipLocationChange: true});
    return false;
  }
}
```

Any ideas on why the URL is changing? Is it an Router mechanic because it can't render the page and is 'failing'?

Comment: "but when it returns false".... are you really returning false? Because it doens't look like so.

Comment: I should have specified I've done it when it does return false it does the same thing as above.

Comment: @NathanielGottschalt
Basic property of skipLocationChange: true.
// Navigate silently to /login
`this.router.navigate(['/login'], { skipLocationChange: true });`.
that why authGuard is navigate to login page but hide url.
actual url  of login is (http://192.168.1.113:4200/#/login) but in this case url look like this (http://192.168.1.113:4200/#/)

Comment: @Abhishek I want it to look the latter but it is not. The url is localhost:4200 for the whole app, I hide all navigate url changes. But this is the only time it changes the URL to localhost:4200/noauthpage and I don't want it to.

Answer (score 2):

found a workaround with it,
once called the

```
this.router.navigate(['noauthpage'], { skipLocationChange: true });
```

you may call

```
this.location.replaceState('current_page');
```

to replace the browser url immediately.